# How does Python know somebody was looping over a dict?

Tags: python, list

If somebody tries:

```
my_dict = {1: 1}
for key in my_dict:
    my_dict.pop(key)
```

one will get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Python will throw an error, since you changed the size of the dict while looping over it.

How does Python know that this has happened, and can this feature be overrided programmatically so that the code runs?

And before somebody asks the inevitable question of "why I would want to do this": I don't. I'm asking a question. It's called curiosity.

FOR EXAMPLE:

Say I have a dict with 5 items. The above code should simply delete all items in the dict!

Comment: Do you mean to add a `5` for each of the elements present in `my_list` before the loop starts?

Comment: No, I want to do it during the loop. And yes, I can just loop over the length of the list rather than its items, but I am asking specifically if I can override Python from throwing an error here.

Comment: Python does NOT throw an error in that case.  It simply creates an infinite loop.  Did you try this?

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I did. Maybe it was a dict? Ah yes, it was a dict! But why is the list behavior different?

Comment: @michael: Yes, that's what I thought - I was just nailing down the requirement: How many `5`s do you want to add?

Comment: @michael list is a different data type, why wouldn't it have different behavior? also dicts can't have duplicate keys

Comment: Question modified with a new example.

Comment: Originally, Python dictionaries had no guaranteed order.  They iterated in whatever order the tree structure happened to supply.  Thus, adding an element could rebalance the tree and scramble the order, rendering the iterator useless.  It wouldn't know where it was any more.

Comment: Here is the relevant CPython source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ac75f6bdd4748b3378dd321f862d13aa1898f77a/Objects/dictobject.c#L3625-L3630

Comment: TimRoberts, I understand it makes sense, but what I'm asking is, regardless of how stupid it may be, if it is possible for me to override this functionality by subclassing dict?

Comment: No.  If the dict changes, no matter how, it will detect that on the next iteration.  Now, you can do `for key in list(my_dict.keys()):`.  With that, you can tweak the dict during the loop, but your new entries won't be part of the iteration.

Comment: The loop isn't iterating over `my_dict` directly, but rather a value of type `dict_keyiterator` that wraps the dict. I think it's the definition of `dict_keyiterator.__next__` that detects the change in size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search through the Python source code for "dictionary changed size during iteration", you'll find `Objects/dictobject.c`:

```c
static PyObject*
dictiter_iternextkey(dictiterobject *di)
{
    /* ... omitted ... */

    if (di->di_used != d->ma_used) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                        "dictionary changed size during iteration");
        di->di_used = -1; /* Make this state sticky */
        return NULL;
    }
```

The `ma_used` field is simply the number of items in the dictionary, as documented in `dictobject.h`:

```c
/* Number of items in the dictionary */
Py_ssize_t ma_used;
```

And `di_used` is simply a copy of that value from when the iterator was created.

You cannot change this programatically, at least, not in any reasonable way (let's not monkey-patch `dict`). You can create your own dictionary type, if you like, and define your own iterator that behaves differently.

The reason why Python does this is because it is hard to figure out what the "correct" thing to do is when you are iterating over a hash table that is changing.

Writing your own hash table implementation is a good exercise, and you'll quickly discover the problem... when you insert or remove entries in a hash table, it may change the order of other entries--is it acceptable for the iterator to skip entries, or return the same entry twice? Probably not. Can you create a data structure that provides the iteration behavior you want? Yes, but it's complicated, and the hash table that does this may perform worse under other scenarios.

Comment: I would rather say the reason Python does this is that dictionaries used to be unordered. With dictionaries preserving insertion order, the behavior could (in theory) be well-defined, similar as mutating a list while iterating.

Comment: @wim: Even if the results could be well-defined, the implementation may be unreasonably complex.

Answer (score 1):

Python object can return their own iterators. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator. So when `__iter__()` is called on a dict object, the dict can set a flag that it is being iterated over. That same flag will be cleared once the internal iterator has consumed all the items in the dict. If any modifications are called on the dict (e.g using `pop`) the function checks the flag to see if the modification can be made or if the dict is still in an iterator loop.